# Is it possible to filter some data from topic instead of moving its data content in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two kafka clusters, Server1 and Server2.
My goal is to send the filtered data from Server1 to Server2.

Here is my simple example.

The topic1 in Server1 has data such as below.

```
Server 1
offset 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  ...
data   a b c a a b c  ...

Server 2
offset 1 2 3 4  ...
data   a a a a  ...
```

What I want to do is that filtering data containing `a` and sending it to Server 2.
Therefore the result looks like as above in `Server 2`.
I know it is simple business logic and it can be easily achieved by filtering method in Kafka Streams Apis.

However, my real case is that the content of data size is larger than above example.
So I think that it is not a good idea to filter and send the original data, because it is almost duplicated between two servers. Instead, it will be better if I can send the filtered index (offset) to `server2` so that the data is not duplicated between two servers.

I have googled it regarding kafka streams in terms of `filter` but no idea to achieve my case.

I would appreciate if you could give any hints or idea to resolve my problem?
Or is it impossible in Kafka Stream?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams only works against a single cluster, so you cannot read data from topic 1 in cluster A, and write to topic 2 in cluster B.

You have multiple options:

- write a Kafka Streams app, that write the result into a topic in cluster A, and mirror the result topic into cluster B.
- try to use SMT in Kafka Connect (ie MirrorMaker 2) to transform and filter while replicating the topic from cluster A to cluster B
- write a custom "plain" consumer/producer app instead of using Kafka Streams